# Customizing content proposal in Xtext for web editors

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I have a DSL written in Xtext. In order to add custom content proposal, I have edited the `MyDslProposalProvider` class in the `ui` project. The new proposals are present when I debug the plugin in Eclipse, but not in the web editor, which is ultimately what I want. I want to set the custom proposals at a single place and all generated editors to use them. Is it possible to do that with Xtext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I had the same problem and struggled a little bit with the solution (as I would like to use both, Eclipse editor and Web editor) I would like to provide some more detailed feedback on a possible solution here, which worked well for me. 
In my solution I did the following steps.

1. Implement a `MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider` in *my.dsl.ide* sub project extending from `IdeContentProposalProvider`, package *my.dsl.ide.contentassistant* (newly created); an example of such an implementation may be found [here](https://github.com/TypeFox/xtext-vscode/blob/master/org.xtext.example.statemachine.ide/src/main/java/org/xtext/example/statemachine/ide/contentassist/StatemachineWebContentProposalProvider.xtend).
   The implementation is not such convenient as at the well known UI proposal provider for Eclipse. I had to implement switch cases based on `MyDslGrammarAccess` elements instead of structural grammar elements like in the UI proposal provider. On the other hand, I have only one proposal implementation for all editor cases that way (DRY principle!).
2. Register the `MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider` at `MyDslIdeModule` in the same project (only with that it works already in the web editor).

   ```
   def Class<? extends IdeContentProposalProvider> bindIdeContentProposalProvider() {
       MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider
   }
   ```
3. Register the new `MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider` **and** the forwarding class `UiToIdeContentProposalProvider` at the `MyDslUiModule` in the *my.dsl.ui* sub project. (That's what took the longest investigation as it cannot be logically derived.)

   ```
   override Class<? extends IContentProposalProvider> bindIContentProposalProvider() {
       return UiToIdeContentProposalProvider
   }

   def Class<? extends IdeContentProposalProvider> bindIdeContentProposalProvider() {
       return JavaPOSConfigLanguageIdeContentProposalProvider
   }
   ```

   For an full example see [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-ide/blob/bc4d92a678589039aecc1508b2e34b0a5eb0d007/jdl/io.github.jhipster.jdl.ui/src/io/github/jhipster/jdl/ui/JDLUiModule.xtend).
4. As I had implemented the `MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider` in the newly created package *my.dsl.ide.contentassistant*, this package has to be exported in the `MANIFEST.MF` file of the sub project *my.dsl.ide* (the subsequent 2 exports were already there). Otherwise i would get an an error *Access restriction: The type is not accessible due to restriction on required project* in the `MyDslUiModule`.

   ```
   Export-Package: my.dsl.ide.contentassist,
     my.dsl.ide.contentassist.antlr,
     my.dsl.ide.contentassist.antlr.internal
   ```

   That way it worked well for for both editors, Eclipse and web.

Thanks Christian again for the initial hint!

... If I could make a wish, I would like to have the same structural grammar element access in the `MyDslIdeContentProposalProvider` as we have it today in UI proposal provider.

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative! I also checked out JHipster and really like it!

Comment: Just one note: I'm not the autor of JHipster. :-) I just used it for examples as my project is closed source.

Answer (score 0):

you need to subclass `org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.contentassist.IdeContentProposalProvider` and bind it in `YourDslIdeModule` and `YourDslUiModule`. Then (in Xtext 2.13) you can use `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.UiToIdeContentProposalProvider` bound in `YourDslUiModule` to delegate to that in eclipse ui.